# How to use arm_kinematics package?

Tags: ros, arm-kinematics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As i am new to ROS platform i need some guidance to use arm_kinematics package for solving FK and IK for basic 5 DOF. In order to understand this package i followed the pr2_kinematics tutorials. But i am getting message while executing the command "rosrun pr2_arm_navigation_tutorials get_fk"

waitForService: Service [/pr2_right_arm_kinematics/get_fk_solver_info] has not been advertised, waiting...

after this there nothing is displaying.Previous to this i got error message

cannot launch node of type [pr2_arm_kinematics_constraint_aware/pr2_arm_kinematics_constraint_aware]: Cannot locate node of type [pr2_arm_kinematics_constraint_aware] in package [pr2_arm_kinematics_constraint_aware]

but pr2_arm_kinematics_constraint_aware.cpp is available in pr2_arm_kinematics_constraint_aware package and it has been added in CmakeList.txt file and also this package path is available in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH variable.I confirmed it by using rospack find command.

Please help me to solve this.

Regards,
Rajeswari

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12925/how-to-use-arm_kinematics-package?/) by [Rajeswari](https://answers.ros.org/users/1753/rajeswari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-02-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2012-02-16**:
You might have already done this, but have you made the pr2_arm_kinematics_constraint_aware a dependence in the manifest of your package and used rosmake to build the pr2_arm_kinematics_constraint_aware binary?

**Comment by [Rajeswari](https://answers.ros.org/users/1753/rajeswari/) on 2012-02-16**:
yes i have added pr2_arm_kinematics_constraint_aware as a dependence in the manifest.xml file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Cannot locate node of type [foo] ... means it can't find the "foo" binary. Are you sure you compiled this package ? Is the foo binary where is it supposed to be ? (in /pr2_arm_kinematics_constraint_aware/bin)

---

Originally posted by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) with karma: 514 on 2012-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0